# How to rename file in bash script one by one

Tags: bash, shell, files, rename

I have loads of files which look like this:

```
data1.csv
data2.csv
.
.
data(n).csv
```

My use case is that when I will call my script it will change `data1.csv to data.csv` and remaining files as it is and next time when I will call my script second time, it will move `data1.csv` to processed folder and change `data2.csv` to `data.csv` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses `data.csv` as a link to the requested file to keep status between iterations.

```
# check to see if an argument is given
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Illegal number of parameters"
        exit
fi

# check if ran before if so move that to processed/ directory
if [ -h "data.csv" ]; then
        prev=`readlink data.csv`
        echo "Found previous run $prev"
        rm -f data.csv  # remove link
        mv -f $prev processed/  # move previous file to processed directory
        echo "Moved to processed/$prev"
fi

# check to see if file exists
if [ -e data$1.csv ]; then
        ln -s data$1.csv data.csv  # link data.csv to the requested file
        echo "Linked data.csv -> data$1.csv"
else
        echo "No such file data$1.csv"
fi
```

Comment: Above script assumes you will give the number of the file to be processed in command line. If you want to sequentially process all files from 1 to n, that can be achieved by parsing the `prev` variable and incrementing the count.

Answer (score 1):

If the file names have no newlines, you can find the first file to process in a bash script by using:

```
first=$(ls --sort=version *.csv | head -1)
ln -s "$first" data.csv
```

however before you rename that file you have to make sure and old existing one is out of the way:

```
#! /bin/bash
if [ -e data.csv ] ; then
   mv $(readlink data.csv) backup_directory
   rm data.csv
fi
```

Combine those in the right order and add the processing of `data.csv` at the end and you can repeatedly invoke the script to process all files.

Comment: In one linear: `[ -e data.css ] && mv data.csv backup_directory || mv "$(ls --sort=version *.csv | head -1)" data.csv`

Comment: And getting rid of that clunky --sort=version: `[ -e data.css ] && mv data.csv backup_directory || mv "$(ls -v *.csv | head -1)" data.csv`

Comment: Anthon, if i execute command second time i can't move data.csv to backup_directory because already data.csv is there in backup_directory, is there any way data.csv file will rename to data1.csv and then move data1.csv to backup_directory?

Comment: @user188979 I changed the answer, now make link and if that exists move the file where it points to before removing the link